# Odata Controller not working with multiple Keys

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata, swagger

I work with an ASP.NET webapi with entity framework and odataV4 controller

First i had one [Key] tag in my model and every controllerAction was shown in the swagger UI

Now i have 3 [Key] tags in my model and only controllerActions with no arguments are shown in the swagger UI

I changed my Model from

```
    //Some other stuff
    [Key]
    public byte first{ get; set; }
    public int second{ get; set; }
    public long third{ get; set; }
    //Some other stuff
```

to

```
      //Some other stuff
    [Key]
    public byte first{ get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int second{ get; set; }
    [Key]
    public long third{ get; set; }
    //Some other stuff
```

and the controllerAction from

`public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put([FromODataUri] byte key, Delta<lists> patch)`

to

`public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put([FromODataUri] byte first, [FromODataUri] int second, [FromODataUri] long third, Delta<lists> patch)`

with one key the Endpoints are shown in the swagger UI and they work, with multiple keys the Endpoints are not shown in the swagger UI and everytime i try to reach the endpoint this error shows up

> "No action was found on the controller 'lists' that matches the request."

I send a PUT Request with `.../myController(first=1,second=1,third=10)` in the URL

What i am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: What @SamXu said and it is also case sensitive, I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version do you use?

As I know, the latest [5.x](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.OData/5.11.0-beta) and [6.x](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.OData/6.1.0-beta) version do support the multiple keys, no matter attribute routing or convention routing you are using.

See the comments in https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/maintenance-V4/src/System.Web.OData/OData/Routing/Conventions/ProcedureRoutingConventionHelpers.cs#L133-L137

So for your scenario, if in convention routing, the parameter name in the method of controller should be prefixed with "key".

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put([FromODataUri] byte keyfirst, [FromODataUri] int keysecond, [FromODataUri] long keythird, Delta<lists> patch)
```

Hope it can help you. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I solved it creating a new EMD Class like this:

```
namespace ODataService.Edm
{
    public static class SampleModelBuilder
    {
        public static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
        {
            ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EntityType<EntityTableName>().HasKey(c => new { c.first, c.second, c.third});
            builder.EntitySet<EntityTableName>("EntityTableName");
            return builder.GetEdmModel();
        }
    }
}
```

And then I repleace the MapODataServiceRoute in the WebApiConfig.cs to invoke my EdmModel:

```
config.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", null, Edm.SampleModelBuilder.GetEdmModel());
```

You can refer more info abot EDM here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/odatalib/edm/build-basic-model

At last, I use some attribute-routing on the controller like this:

```
[EnableQuery]
[ODataRoute("EntityTableName({first},{second},{third})")]
public SingleResult<EntityTableName> Get([FromODataUri] byte first, [FromODataUri] int second, [FromODataUri] long third)
{
    IQueryable<EntityTableName> result = dbContext.EntityTableName.Where(p => p.first == first && p.second == second && p.third == third);
    return SingleResult.Create(result);
}
```

To extend the info about attribute routing check this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/odata/webapi/attribute-routing

Let me know if this help you.
Good luck and great coding!